# upload excel file validation in java

Tags: java

i am new for upload Excel file POI API so i need to validate duplicate cell in particular column . example like

```
String dupcolumn  = myRow.getcell(0);
Iterator iter = new Iterator();
while(iter.hesnext())
{
myRow = (Row) iter.next();

dupcolumn.contains(iter.toString());


}
```

Above code cannot support to read in particular column , but always continuous reading column .

Comment: Now i have write code like that String[] dupcolumn = myRow.getcell(0); boolean dup =true; if(dup){for(int i=0 ; i<dupcolumn.length;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<dupcolumn .length;j++){if(dupcolumn [j]==dupcolumn [i]){System.out.println("Duplicate cell");}}} this code is correct .

Answer (score 6):

This code may helpful to you.

```
InputStream xlsStream = excelFileUpload.getInputstream();
XSSFWorkbook wb  = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rows=sheet.iterator();
//need to keep retrieved values in a collection to check duplicates. 
Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();

//check all rows in excel sheet
while(rows.hasNext()){
    //get next row
    XSSFRow row =(XSSFRow)rows.next();
    //pass '0' means first cell (column) in current row. if you need to get other cell value, you can pass relevant cell number instead of '0'. 
    XSSFCell cell=row.getCell(0);
    if(values.contains(cell.getStringCellValue())){
        //duplicated value
    }else{
        values.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: its useful code me . but i have check cell space , @, #,like special  characters  in java

Comment: Now i have write code like that String[] dupcolumn = myRow.getcell(0); boolean dup =true; if(dup){for(int i=0 ; i<dupcolumn.length;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<dupcolumn .length;j++){if(dupcolumn [j]==dupcolumn [i]){System.out.println("Duplicate cell");}}} this code is correct .